# Apache Curator lock path

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

We know how to create a distributed shared lock using Apache Curator:

```
InterProcessMutex lock = new InterProcessMutex(client,"/my/lock");
```

For the above code, I have two questions:

1: The second parameter is the path to lock(znode), so is this lock znode created by this period of code automatically, or we need to create it manually before?

2: If it is created by "InterProcessMutex", what if this lock znode has been created by other instances already? Does it throw any "znode exsting" exception? If it doesn't throw any exception, what happened, create a duplicate znode?

Answer (score 3):

For 1 - yes, Curator creates the path (and parents if needed) for you.

For 2 - If other instances allocate an InterProcessMutex with that path there is no issue. It's all handled internally. Curator creates the paths if needed. Think of the path as a "lock id".

Dislaimer: I'm the main author of Curator

Comment: So when Curator does "release", the path is removed or not

Comment: No, it's not removed. Curator does, however, have a separate recipe (Reaper) that can be used to clean up old paths like this.